# Tapestry 5.36 deployed on Jetty 9, encoding issue

Tags: encoding, jetty, debian, locale, tapestry

I just deployed my Tapestry 5 app on Jetty 9 web server, running on Debian Squeeze. I have problem with encoding. I can't see Serbian letters (šđčćž). For example, I see "Dobrodošli" as "Dobrodo??li". You can check it out [HERE](http://cls.metropolitan.ac.rs/elearning). As I know, Tapestry by default works with UTF8, on Debian locale is set SR Latin UTF8, and on Jetty I can't find any config setting where I could set it. I did the same thing local on my PC (Ubuntu 12.10), and everything works great. 
Can you help me please? How to solve this problem, I don't know what I did wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I faced the same problem. I think when you write your text in TML this gives you the problem. If you generate it though the Java code it will appear (as I remember)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting value for `tapestry.charset`.

> The character encoding used when generating output (or parsing input).
>   The default is "UTF-8".

For details checkout http://tapestry.apache.org/configuration.html